# Get N elements from array and if array is smaller than N, fill remaining elements by some value

Tags: ruby

I'm curious what would be a better way of doing this?

This code obvious doesn't work since `take` expects only one argument, but this is how I wish it would work

```
%w(a b c).take(5, "x") # => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = %w(a b c)
(0...5).map{|i| a[i] || "x"}
```

Here's a version that works with arrays containing `nil` values:

```
a = %w(a b c)
(0...5).map{|i| a.fetch(i,"x")}
```

Comment: That's good because it's simple, but it precludes using it with arrays containing `nil` values.

Comment: @tokland I just added a version that addresses arrays containing `nil` values :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a non-destructive solution:

```
class Array
 def pad_and_take(n, x)
   self.dup.fill(x, self.length...n).take(n)
 end
end

# then you can do:
%w(a b c).pad_and_take(5, "x") # => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def take2 n, v
    self.fill v, n
    self.take n
  end
end

a1 = [:a, :b, :c, :d]
p a1.take2 2, 123
p a1
a2 = (1..10).to_a
p a2.take2 3, :hownow
p a2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
cs = ["a", "b", "c"]
cs_padded = cs.take(5) + ["x"] * [5 - cs.size, 0].max
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant of sawa's answer:

```
a = %w(a b c)

(0...5).map { |i| a.fetch(i, "x") }
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

It also works for falsy values:

```
a = ["a", nil, false]

(0...5).map { |i| a.fetch(i, "x") }
#=> ["a", nil, false, "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, replace the x with whatever you'd like:

```
(%w(a b c) << ("x,"*5).split(",")).flatten.take(5).inspect
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(%w(a b c)+["x"]*5).take(5)
```

I'd go with sawa's answer tough - unless Ruby get a function for generating an infinite repeat sequence, this solution forces you to write the number twice.

Answer (score 0):

pad thai =P

```
class Array
  #make array from first n elements, padding with s if n>self.size
  def pad_thai n, s='x'
    sz = self.size
    n>sz ? self+[s]*(n-sz) : self.first(n)
  end
end

ar = %w(a b c)
p ar.pad_thai 2  #["a", "b"]
p ar.pad_thai 5  #["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some Hash magic would be nice.

```
# hard-coded example
array = %w[a b c]
hash  = Hash[(0...array.size).zip array]
hash.default = 'x'
hash.values_at(*0...5)
# => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

As a function,

```
def padded_take(array, count, pad)
  hash = Hash[(0...array.size).zip array]
  hash.default = pad
  hash.values_at(*0...count)
end
padded_take(%w[a b c], 5, 'x')
# => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a quick answer, but if this is used in several places in a production system, I would go for an overkill and use `Enumerator`.

```
def padded_take(array, count, pad)
  e = Enumerator.new do |y|
    array.each { |v| y << v }
    [pad].cycle { |pad| y << pad }
  end
  e.take(count)
end
padded_take(%w[a b c], 10, 'x')
# => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
```

It should be quite easy to extract this behavior into a `PaddedArray` class.